# pyinstaller and python's sh module

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller

I have a python project which i built into a single executable on Linux using pyinstaller. The python also uses python's *sh* module.

While running the single executable, it seems the following commands do not work:

```
getattr(sh, 'mount')
getattr(sh, 'ls')
```

Although when i check the `os.environ['PATH']` that is set correctly and the following work:

```
sh.which('mount') -> /bin/mount
```

I understand that `sh` module behaves differently than other python packages as it dynamically import commands. etc.

Is that causing a problem with pyinstaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your issue more exactly:

```
cat > test.py << EOF
import sh
ls = getattr(sh, 'ls')
print(ls('-d', '/tmp'))
EOF
```

Normally, this works fine:

```
$ python test.py
/tmp
```

But with PyInstaller, AttributeError is raised:

```
$ ./pyinstaller test.py
$ ./dist/test/test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ls'
```

You are correct, *PyInstaller* has a custom module loader, which does not interplay well with the *sh* module. Briefly.

This can be resolved by reproducing the same "Magic" that *sh.Environment.__getitem__* method performs.

We may modify test.py as follows:

```
import sh

ls = sh.Command._create('ls')
print(ls('-d', '/tmp'))
```

and this works fine.

```
$ ./pyinstaller test.py
$ ./dist/test/test
/tmp
```

*sh.py* overloads *sys.modules[__name__]* with an instance of *sh.SelfWrapper*. This is where it conflicts with *PyInstaller*, whose custom Module importer does not evaluate sys.modules as standard python.